# Most Common Value in Java

Tags: java

So I've found a way to print the most frequent value's frequency for when the pair of dice is rolled 100000 times. However, I don't how to display the most common value instead of how many times it comes up. Please help.

Current results:
16716 (This is the number of times the most common value came up, but not the most common value.)
Results:
The average is 6.98691.
The standard deviation is 4.70269534109257.
Each "*" represents one percent.

The total number of rolls is one hundred thousand.

Index   Value   Percent

2:  2815*    
3:  5603    ******
4:  8307    ********
5:  11148   ***********
6:  14031   **************
7:  16716   *****************
8:  13821   **************
9:  11071   ***********
10: 8289    ********
11: 5399    *****
12: 2800    *

Main class:

```
public class Alpha {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Histogram();
}

public static void Histogram() {

    int rolls = 0;
    int[] getFrequency = new int [13]; //Declares the array
    int total;
    int scale;
    int maxValue = 0;
    double frequency;
    double average;
    double Average;
    double stdev;
    double getTotal = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    Bravo dice;
    dice = new Bravo();;

    rolls = 100000;

    //Roll the dice
    for (int i=0; i<rolls; i++) {
        dice.roll();
        getFrequency[dice.getTotal()]++;
        sum += dice.getTotal();
        average = sum / rolls;
        getTotal += Math.pow((dice.getTotal()-average),2);
    }

    for (total = 2; total < getFrequency.length; total++) {
        if (getFrequency[total] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = (int) getFrequency[total];
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxValue);

    average = sum / rolls;
    Average = getTotal / rolls;
    stdev = Math.sqrt(Average);

    System.out.println("Results:" + "\n" + 
    "The average is " + average + "." + "\n" + 
    "The standard deviation is " + stdev + "." + "\n"+ 
    "Each " + '\"' + "*" + '\"' + " represents one percent.");
    System.out.println("The total number of rolls is one hundred thousand.");
    System.out.println("Index\tValue\tPercent");

    //output dice rolls
    for (total=2; total<getFrequency.length; total++){ 
        System.out.print(total + ": \t"+getFrequency[total]+"\t");
        frequency = (double) getFrequency[total] / rolls;
        scale = (int) Math.round(frequency * 100);

        for (int i=0; i<scale; i++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Secondary Class:

```
public class Bravo {
private int die1;   
    private int die2;   
    public Bravo() {
        roll(); 
    }
    public void roll() {
        die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
        die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    }
    public int getDie1() {
        return die1;
    }
    public int getDie2() {
        return die2;
    }
    public int getTotal() {
        return die1 + die2;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modify the for loop:

```
int modeValue=2;
for (total = 2; total < getFrequency.length; total++) {
    if (getFrequency[total] > maxValue) {
        maxValue = (int) getFrequency[total];
        modeValue = total;
    }
    else {

    }
}
System.out.println("Most common value is" + modeValue);
```